# How can I create a object defined by a webservice factory function in powershell?

Tags: web-services, powershell, soap, factory

In python, if I connect to a SOAP web service, I can do something like this to create an object using a factory function:

```
defdObj = WSObject.factory("ns0:MyObjectType")
```

In powershell, I can create a new web service, but I don't see any factory functions:

```
$WSObject = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri http://www.example.com/webservice?wsdl
```

Is it possible to create an object that is defined in a web service, using powershell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call New-WebServiceProxy with a namespace, you'll be able to easily create objects that are defined in the wsdl. Here is an example:

```
$WSObject = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri http://www.example.com/webservice?wsdl -Namespace <MyCustomNamespaceName>
$CustomObject = New-Object <MyCustomNamespaceName>.<DefinedObjectClass>
```

Then `$CustomObject` will be the correct type, and will have the necessary functions/properties.